# How does HDInsigh Spark work with following code

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-hdinsight

I am new to Spark and HDInsight. I am wondering how below code works? I mean how jobs are scheduled among cluster nodes. suppose I have 2 head nodes and 4 work nodes, which codes will be running on head nodes and which codes will be running on work nodes?

How can I let the Spark know I want some code to be executed on work nodes?

```
// the code is from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/spark/apache-spark-eventhub-streaming
import com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs._
val pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)
val eventHubClient = EventHubClient.create(connStr.toString(), pool)

def sendEvent(message: String) = {
      val messageData = EventData.create(message.getBytes("UTF-8"))
      eventHubClient.get().send(messageData)
      println("Sent event: " + message + "\n")
}

import twitter4j._
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory
import twitter4j.Twitter
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder

// Twitter application configurations
// Replace values below with yours   
val twitterConsumerKey = "<CONSUMER KEY>"
val twitterConsumerSecret = "<CONSUMER SECRET>"
val twitterOauthAccessToken = "<ACCESS TOKEN>"
val twitterOauthTokenSecret = "<TOKEN SECRET>"

val cb = new ConfigurationBuilder()
cb.setDebugEnabled(true).setOAuthConsumerKey(twitterConsumerKey).setOAuthConsumerSecret(twitterConsumerSecret).setOAuthAccessToken(twitterOauthAccessToken).setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(twitterOauthTokenSecret)

val twitterFactory = new TwitterFactory(cb.build())
val twitter = twitterFactory.getInstance()

// Getting tweets with keyword "Azure" and sending them to the Event Hub in realtime!

val query = new Query(" #Azure ")
query.setCount(100)
query.lang("en")
var finished = false
while (!finished) {
  val result = twitter.search(query)
  val statuses = result.getTweets()
  var lowestStatusId = Long.MaxValue
  for (status <- statuses.asScala) {
    if(!status.isRetweet()){
      sendEvent(status.getText())
    }
    lowestStatusId = Math.min(status.getId(), lowestStatusId)
    Thread.sleep(2000)
  }
  query.setMaxId(lowestStatusId - 1)
}

// Closing connection to the Event Hub
eventHubClient.get().close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow and Azure!

It is easy to understand the components of Spark by understanding how Spark runs on HDInsight clusters.

[image]

Spark applications run as independent sets of processes on a cluster, coordinated by the SparkContext object in your main program (called the driver program).

[image]

The SparkContext can connect to several types of cluster managers, which allocate resources across applications. These cluster managers include Apache Mesos, Apache Hadoop YARN, or the Spark cluster manager. In HDInsight, Spark runs using the YARN cluster manager. Once connected, Spark acquires executors on workers nodes in the cluster, which are processes that run computations and store data for your application. Next, it sends your application code (defined by JAR or Python files passed to SparkContext) to the executors. Finally, SparkContext sends tasks to the executors to run.

The SparkContext runs the user's main function and executes the various parallel operations on the worker nodes. Then, the SparkContext collects the results of the operations. The worker nodes read and write data from and to the Hadoop distributed file system. The worker nodes also cache transformed data in-memory as Resilient Distributed Datasets (RDDs).

The SparkContext connects to the Spark master and is responsible for converting an application to a directed graph (DAG) of individual tasks that get executed within an executor process on the worker nodes. Each application gets its own executor processes, which stay up for the duration of the whole application and run tasks in multiple threads.

Hope this helps.